# "Declare" loop creates output for only one of the variables

Tags: bash, loops, declare

I have written a script to create a loop for a software I'm running:

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -a pops=("pop1" "pop2" "pop3")

for target in "${pops[@]}";
do
while IFS= read target
do
    parFile=./input/paramfile.1b.$target.txt
    sed "s/PROPIND/0/g; s/BOOTSTRAP/1/g; s/NULLIND/1/g; s/OUTPUT/globetrotter.1/g; s/TARGET/$target/g" ./input/paramfile.txt > $parFile
name=globetrotter.1b.$target
R < myscript.R ./input/paramfile.1a.$target.txt ./input/samplefile.txt ./input/recomfile.txt 1 --save > ./output/log.$name
    break
done
done
```

The program runs just for the first population and then it stops. For this reason I believe the loop is not written correctly.
Is the break in the wrong spot?

Thank you.

Comment: Hmmmm... May be you forgot `$target` instead of `target` in your while loop ?

Comment: Also I'm not sure if `while IFS= read target` could works.
May be `echo $target | while IFS= read` is better, but I don't understand exactly that your script is doing.

Comment: Basically what I did is: declare my 3 variables (the populations) and then start the loop in which the target is each population. Read the target (so each pop) and perform the following script. This is what I wanted in my mind. I believe it partially works as it reads the first population and it correctly creates a parameter file with its name as I indicated. Then it perform all the analysis of my R script without issues. But then it won't loop, by doing the second population. I will try with your suggestion to see if it loops

Comment: Maybe `while IFS= read target; do` and the corresonding `done` are unnecessary because you are already constructing the loop with `for`.

Comment: I will try this as well and see if it works, thanks

Comment: @tshiono is right: remove the `while` loop, it is useless. If you want to iterate more than once also remove the `break` statement. And try maybe to indent your code correctly, it will be easier to read, understand, debug, maintain...

Comment: @Gf.Ena : Thanks for details. But are the "pop1", "pop2" and "pop3" are the files ? Or just the variables ?
If it's just the variable, as it said Renaud, what is the purpose of second (while) loop ?

Comment: Yes it is the variables, not the files. The point is that I originally wrote a first general script in which I looped the creation of such "parameters" files (that needed to be created even if using only 1 single pop), then I wanted to integrate in the loop the "declare" and I thought it was necessary to maintain also the previous loop. Thank you